# Cursor-based paging with a compound index in MongoDB and Python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

The Python application I'm implementing works with the MongoDB database. I use the `mongoengine` module to connect and fetch data in my scripts (https://docs.mongoengine.org/).

My collection in the database has following structure:

```
class Item(mongoengine.Document):
    timestamp = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    ... // the rest of the fields, the _id is added automatically
```

I'm trying to implement the cursor-based paging based on the compound index created with `_id` and `timestamp`. The primary reason for this is I want to order by data by the timestamp. However multiple items may have the same timestamp (year, month, day, without hours, minutes and seconds). Thus, I also need to add the `_id` field to the compound index.
My understanding is that following list of items:

```
Item2, _id=1, timestamp=2024,1,2
Item1, _id=2, timestamp=2024,1,1
Item3, _id=3, timestamp=2024,1,3
Item4, _id=4, timestamp=2024,1,3
```

should be sorted like this:

```
Item4, _id=4, timestamp=2024,1,3
Item3, _id=3, timestamp=2024,1,3
Item2, _id=1, timestamp=2024,1,2
Item1, _id=2, timestamp=2024,1,1
```

So I tried adding a following compound index to the `Item` class:

```
meta = {
    "indexes": [
        {
            "name": "myindex",
            "fields": ["-timestamp", "_id"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The minus sign before `timestamp`, according to the documentation, means it's sorted in the descending order of timestamp field. In the case two items have the same timestamp, they should be sorted in the ascending order by the `_id` field.

The above does not work. So I tried to create a compound index using only one field, `timestamp`. This also doesn't work, no matter what order I choose (with minus before the field name or without it).

I read MongoDB documentation and they say there's a `hint()` command to force database to use the specified index. According to the documentation of the `mongoengine` module (https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=hint#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.hint), it also supports this command.

So I tried the following code to enforce using my index:

```
models.Item.objects(id=id).hint(index="myindex").limit(10)
```

So my expectation is the above command would fetch data, sort it according to the compound index I'm trying to enforce, use the provided `id` to give only 10 entries after the entry with the id provided. It also doesn't work at all.

Does `mongoengine` module supports compound indexes and `hint()` command? Is the above code correct?

---

EDIT

I found out that the reason I don't see the difference in my unit tests with different compound indexes is the fact that mongomock seems to not supporting compound indexes.
**So the only question left is how should the cursor-based pagination be implemented with a collection based on compound indexes? The `mongoengine` does not allow to provide `hint()` before querying the collection (`objects()`.**

Comment: You say "doesn't work" several times. But what, specifically, do you mean in each case? For example when you've created the compound index, is it not being used? Are you receiving an error? Something else? Also, are you requesting the data be returned in sorted order when you are querying for it?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the compound index is not used at all, even when I use hint() function to enforce it. Also, no matter whether I put "-" sign to change ascending/descending order in the index, I don't see any change in the results.

The request to fetch data is shown above: models.Item.objects(id=id).hint(index="myindex").limit(10)

Comment: I found out that the reason I don't see the difference in my unit tests with different compound indexes is the fact that mongomock seems to not supporting compound indexes.